# Google Nest Camera Access

Tags: nest-device-access

Can we access nest camera from different location. E.g We have shop in different cities with Nest camera installed. Can I have control/Access to all the camera from main office with Google Device access API.

Answer (score 0):

When you access the API of a Google/Nest device it is a Cloud API and not locally in the camera.

So yes you can access the API anywhere.